# AudioTrack WRITE_BLOCKING vs WRITE_NON_BLOCKING

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing, audiotrack

I am trying to figure out exactly how Android AudioTrack works. One point of confusion for me is the write mode.

The [documentation for the write() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack#write(float[],%20int,%20int,%20int)) indicates that you can pass either a write mode [WRITE_BLOCKING or WRITE_NON_BLOCKING](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#WRITE_BLOCKING).

Based on the descriptions, does WRITE_BLOCKING block until all data has been played? So for example, if I have a buffer of mono audio at 44100 of size 2048 samples, calling write with WRITE_BLOCKING will block for 2048 * (1000.0 / 44100) milliseconds? Does this not mean that as soon as the write is complete, that you are immediately in a buffer underrun scenario?

Comment: The documentation for `AudioTrack.write` states that _"If the write mode is `WRITE_BLOCKING`, the write will normally block until all the data **has been enqueued** for playback"_. That doesn't mean that actual playback of that data has started yet. It may be sitting in a buffer waiting to be processed by the mixer.

Comment: In the WRITE_BLOCKING description is uses the word "written" in place of "enqueued". These multiple terms are sort of confusing me as to what is actually happening under the hood.

Comment: Well, Android is open source in case you want to investigate it further. For example, you can google _"android googlesource AudioTrack.java"_ and _"android googlesource AudioTrack.cpp"_.

Comment: ya that is an ultimate option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael mentioned, it blocks until the data has been enqueued. This is the same meaning as in the description for `WRITE_BLOCKING`; it blocks until the data has been *written* to the internal buffer (the one for which you specified the size, during construction).

`write( ..., 2048, WRITE_BLOCKING )` will block for approximately 2048 * (1000.0 / 44100) seconds, if the buffer is already full (data hasn't been played yet). If `write()` does block for any length of time, once it returns, you can be reasonably sure the internal buffer is maximally filled. In the absence of any further `write()s`, the `AudioTrack` will continue to supply the mixer with audio output, until the internal buffer is exhausted.

This design (internal buffer) is supposed to help you avoid buffer underruns. The bigger your buffer is, the longer you can go without a `write()`.

Comment: So if I always properly calculate the available space in the buffer using getPlaybackHeadPosition, and only write appropiately sized buffers, WRITE_BLOCKING should never actually block? EG if there is only room for 5 frames and I only write 5 frames, it will not block.